# Unable to register IRequestPreProcessors with Mediatr

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, mediatr

I want to register the following dummy IRequestPreProcessor (Mediator 3)

```
public class IdentifyUserTypeCommandHandler : IRequestPreProcessor<RegisterUserCommand>
{
    private readonly IOptions<TecApiOptions> _options;

    public IdentifyUserTypeCommandHandler(IOptions<TecApiOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public async Task Process(RegisterUserCommand request)
    {
        request.Type = "internal";
        await Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

To do so, I have my container setup to map IRequestPreProcessor to my concrete implementation IdentifyUserTypeCommandHandler

```
        // Pipeline engine used internally to simplify controllers
        services.AddMediatR();
        // Pre-processors
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestPreProcessor<RegisterUserCommand>), typeof(IdentifyUserTypeCommandHandler));

        // Registers command validator
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IValidator<RegisterUserCommand>), typeof(RegisterUserCommandValidator));

        // Registers generic behaviors
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(Pipeline<,>));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPreProcessorBehavior<,>));
```

As soon as I run the code, I get the following exception

> System.ArgumentException: Open generic service type 'MediatR.Pipeline.IRequestPreProcessor`1[TRequest]' requires registering an open generic implementation type.

I want to run this pre-processor only for commands of type RegisterUserCommand. Any idea on how I can solve this issue?

FYI for the records,

```
public class LoggingBehavior<TCommand, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TCommand, TResponse>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public LoggingBehavior(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory?.CreateLogger(typeof(TCommand).Name) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TCommand request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.RUN_HANDLER, $"Handling '{typeof(TCommand).Name}'");
            var response = await next();
            _logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.RUN_HANDLER, $"Handled '{typeof(TResponse).Name}'");
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(
                LoggingEvents.RUN_HANDLER_EXCEPTION, e,
                $"An error occured while processing pipeline '{GetType().Name}' [{typeof(TCommand).Name} >> {typeof(TResponse).Name}]");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Regards,
Seb

Comment: I'm assuming that `LoggingBehavior<T>` and `ValidationBehavior<T>` are decorators. The way you are trying to register (`IPipelineBehavior<,>`) decorators however by stacking them up will not work with the .NET Core container. .NET Core has no support for decorators. In case there is a non-generic registration, that registration will come first, otherwise the last registration will be selected, but it will be cyclic depending on itself.

Comment: @Steven I have checked and it seems my behaviors are working as expected (at least when I debug my app). I mostly followed what is mentioned here >> https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors

Comment: Ah, I see, the pipeline behaviors are _not_ decorators. Well I wholeheartly disagree with this: "It's a more natural way to enhance your handlers with behavior" and this is true "better supported in containers", but that's IMO a bad argument for not doing 'the right thing'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after talking to the lib's creator, it seems that Pre & Post processors must have a generic definition.

```
public class GenericRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse>
```

OR

```
public class GenericRequestPreProcessor<TRequest> : IRequestPreProcessor<TRequest>
```

src: [Examples](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/tree/master/samples/MediatR.Examples)

The `<TRequest>` and `<TRequest, TResponse>` are required when creating a new Pre/Post processors. Now the 1 000 000$ dollars question I will try to answer later:

> How do we specialize processors so they deal with a specific set of requests/commands (without having to check request type)...

Comment: Hi. The answer later thing. When is that? ;)

Comment: @Kiksen I found that you can just register each processor like this             
 
`container.Register(
Component.For(typeof(IRequestPostProcessor<FooCommand, FooResponse>)).ImplementedBy<FooCommandPostProcessor>());`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `services.AddMediatR()`

Ensure that you register the built-in behaviour: `RequestPreProcessorBehavior`

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPreProcessorBehavior<,>));
services.AddMediatR();
```

Then your pre-processor **needs** to have generic definition as per @Sebastien's answer:

```
public class PingDecorator<TRequest> : IRequestPreProcessor<TRequest>
{
    public Task Process(TRequest request)
    {
        return Unit.Task;
    }
}
```

If you want your pre-processor to be only used with a specific request:

```
public class PingDecorator<TRequest> : IRequestPreProcessor<TRequest> where TRequest:Ping
{
    public Task Process(TRequest request)
    {
        request.Message = request.Message + " Decorated";
        return Unit.Task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version has built-in registration using retrieving from the assembly, no need for registration.
Note that I have tested it with multiple IRequestPreProcessor implementations and all of them are working in the same order they were written in code. I think it could be a semantic error, as logically it should not have only a single RequestPreProcessor.